# How to reduce the vertical distance before a \begin{addmargin}

Tags: spacing

I have the following texts. My problem is that between my text and myothertext a distance is inserted that is about the equal of a full line. As I want to avoid this but not sure as to how I can do that my question is how can I reduce this vertical distance?

```
Mytext
\begin{addmargin}[0.3cm]{0cm}
    MyOtherText
\end{addmargin}
```

for the documentclass I'm using its this one:

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=listof,parskip=full, openany]{scrbook}
```

Comment: Where does `addmargin` come from? I suspect some `\abovedisplayskip` etc. to be changed, but without knowing the package...

Comment: you mean which documentclass I'm using? else addmargin is a standard thing (like itemize) where I don't need to import additional things.

Comment: Nope, `addmargin` is an KOMA extension, apparently. It's not in the LaTeX kernel or in the standard classes ;-)

Comment: that is the default behaviour. `addmargin` starts a new paragraph and with your setting of `parksip=full` you'll get an empty line for the paragraph skip.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ah sorry overlooked that (didn't see that when I looked it up).

Comment: @Herbert is it possible to deactivate this just for the addmargins?

Comment: @Thomas: see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,]{scrartcl}
\makeatletter
\let\@addmarginORIG\@addmargin
\renewcommand*\@addmargin{%
    \vspace{-\bigskipamount}
    \@addmarginORIG}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Mytext
\begin{addmargin}[0.3cm]{0cm}
        MyOtherText
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked tnx. (for me in particular it was medskipamount but that aside works nicely tnx)

Answer (score 4):

You are using `parskip=full` and `scrbook` duly obeys it: `addmargin` starts a new paragraph and so it is separated from the preceding paragraph with a full parskip.

If you want to remove the parskip in your `addmargin` environment, I suggest you to define a new environment.

```
\documentclass[
  parskip=full
]{scrartcl}

\newenvironment{thomasaddmargin}
 {\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 1pt}\addmargin}
 {\endaddmargin}

\begin{document}

Mytext
\begin{thomasaddmargin}[0.3cm]{0cm}
MyOtherText
\end{thomasaddmargin}

Mytext

Mytext

\end{document}
```

If you want to follow the “remove the vertical space approach”, you have to patch the right command, which is not `\@addmargin`, but the internal one called by it. This is easy with `xpatch`; note that the glue to remove is `\parskip`, not `\bigskipamount`.

```
\documentclass[
  parskip=full
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@addmargin}{\vspace{-\parskip}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Mytext
\begin{addmargin}[0.3cm]{0cm}
MyOtherText
\end{addmargin}

Mytext

Mytext

\end{document}
```

The output is the same because there is only one paragraph in the `addmargin` environment.

The difference between the two solutions is that in the former no parskip will be used between paragraphs inside `addmargin`; the normal parskip will be used in the latter solution. Take your pick.

Final exhortation: *don't* use `parskip=full`.

Comment: The sad thing is, that apparently the OP didn't upvote any answer :-( +1 though, not just for the very last line :-)